# How can I host a website and web application on the same server using AWS?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, flask

Excuse my lack of server architecture knowledge, but I'm a bit confused on what applications, servers, environments, etc.. are and how they can communicate with each other. I just got AWS and here is what I want to do ultimately.

I want to create a Google Chrome extension. For simplicity, lets say that I'm trying to make an app that records the number of times that all users with the extension collectively visit a given webpage plus information about the visits, such as the time they visited and duration. So if I go to Facebook.com and 100 other people with the extension did, I would see an iframe, lets say, that says "100 users have been here and they visited at these times: ...". Of course, the extension also needs to communicate with the server to increase the count by one. The point is, there is no need to visit any webpage for this app to work since it's an extension and the point isn't to go to a webpage, although it still returns HTML and Javascript.

Now, I also want a homepage for the app in case people are interested in the extension for whatever reason. Just like Adblock, you don't need to go to their actual website, but it's good to have one.

My question is, how do I set this up? Do I just have a normal website, ie. www.example.com/ and set it up normally with Wordpress (what I'd like to use) then just designate one address, ie www.example.com/app, to be answered by my Python app? If so, how do I do that? What do I need in AWS? I'm familiar with Flask and have written apps on my local server using it—can that be integrated with Wordpress?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: You can use Apache VirtualHost in EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also want a homepage for the app in case people are interested in
>   the extension

The simplest is to host the home page as a static website (Html, css, js) in an [S3 bucket.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

But if you really want WordPress, [you can do that too.](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/)

For Backend web services for your plugin to talk to, you can use [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html), it is a very simple way to do that, without tinkering all the components yourself.